# How can you make a decimal input valid?

Tags: java, intermediate-code

I have written this code, however, every time I input a decimal value, it doesn't work. How can I make this code work even if I input a decimal value? For example, if I input a value of 7.5, it should display that "the shipping cost is $9.45"

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class IfElse {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int marksObtained;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a package weight in pounds:");

    marksObtained = input.nextInt();

    if (marksObtained>20)
        {
            System.out.println("The package is too heavy to be shipped");
        }
        else if (marksObtained>10)
        {
            System.out.println("The shipping cost is $12.50");
        }
            else if (marksObtained>3)
        {
            System.out.println("The shipping cost is $9.45");
        }
            else if (marksObtained>1)
        {
            System.out.println("The shipping cost is $4.95");
        }
            else if (marksObtained>0)
        {
            System.out.println("The shipping cost is $2.95");
        }
        else if (marksObtained<0)
        {
            System.out.println("The weight must be greater than zero");
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: hint: `nextInt()` to get floats/doubles?

Comment: if you want to read decimal use `nextDouble()` and also check else if conditions

Comment: Glad to see that you have it sorted.  Please upvote and accept an answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nextFloat` or `nextDouble`

```
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
float a = s.nextFloat ();
System.out.println(a);
```

Using `nextInt` will expect an int value to be entered and will throw a `java.util.InputMismatchException` if a `int` is not entered

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code that you use to read input:

```
int marksObtained;`enter code here`
marksObtained = input.nextInt();
```

The key here is to understand that an `int` can only represent whole number values, not decimals. For decimals, you need to use a double or a float. For example:

```
double marksObtained = input.nextDouble();
```

I suggest you go back and review the basic data types which Java supports. You should also familiarize yourself with [the documentation for the Scanner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) as well as the rest of the documentation for the standard Java APIs.

Answer (score 1):

`nextInt()` only works for integers. Use `nextDouble()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `nextDouble` method as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double marksObtained;

    System.out.println("Please enter a package weight in pounds:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    marksObtained = input.nextDouble();
    input.close();

    if (marksObtained > 20) {
        System.out.println("The package is too heavy to be shipped");
    } else if (marksObtained > 10) {
        System.out.println("The shipping cost is $12.50");
    } else if (marksObtained > 3) {
        System.out.println("The shipping cost is $9.45");
    } else if (marksObtained > 1) {
        System.out.println("The shipping cost is $4.95");
    } else if (marksObtained > 0) {
        System.out.println("The shipping cost is $2.95");
    } else if (marksObtained < 0) {
        System.out.println("The weight must be greater than zero");
    }
}
```

And close the scanner, it is good practice doing it.